# How to make parallel-ssh stop prompting for password?

Tags: ssh, parallel-ssh

I have passwordless ssh setup between the 2 machines. ssh doesn't prompt for password but pssh does. I cannot run commands which need data piped into pssh as the prompt messes with the input. How to make it not prompt for password ? (By the way I just have to press enter without actually typing password)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on net not long after posting the question.

The solution is:

1. Install and use sshpass
2. Use interactive mode to force the password which is just an empty string
3. Used command `cat local | sshpass -ppassword parallel-ssh -I -h new_hosts -l root -A 'cat >> remote'`

Original solution at:
http://www.getreu.net/public/downloads/doc/Secure_Computer_Cluster_Administration_with_SSH/

Comment: Any other answers welcome.